# Why i cannot find context menu strip in my form?

Tags: vb.net, object, controls

I'am trying to find my context menu strip in my form but my code doesnt seem to displayed my desired output...here is my code:

```
Dim omnuStrip() As Object = oCollection.controls.find("mnuStrip", True)
Dim mnuStrip_ as ContextMenuStrip = DirectCast(omnuStrip,ContextMenuStrip)
mnuStrip_.Tag = "My Control"
```

it always return a empty array of objects...Am I doing wrong here? Please help..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContextMenuStrips are added to components, not controls, that's why you get an empty array.

```
Dim strip As ContextMenuStrip = Nothing

For Each component As Object In components.Components
    strip = TryCast(component, ContextMenuStrip)
    If strip IsNot Nothing Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: another thing...is UserControl also has Components?
for example oComponents is a UserControl and not a Windows Form.